# How to run ENTRYPOINT as root and switch to non-root to run CMD using gosu?

Tags: bash, docker

To connect to my container from **Azure WebApp** admin I need to start ssh server at startup. Then I need to run web server once the db is up.

In my Dockerfile I create a dedicated non-root user to run the web server.

```
RUN groupadd -g 1000 wagtail && \
    useradd -u 1000 wagtail -m -d /home/wagtail -g wagtail
```

I copy `startup-ssh.sh` and `startup-main.sh` scripts into the container:

```
COPY startup-ssh.sh /app/
COPY startup-main.sh /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/startup-ssh.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/startup-main.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/app/startup-ssh.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/app/startup-main.sh"]
```

In the `startup-ssh.sh` I start the ssh server and then use **gosu** to switch user:

```
#!/bin/bash

# start ssh server
sed -i "s/SSH_PORT/$SSH_PORT/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
/usr/sbin/sshd

# restore /app directory rights
chown -R wagtail:wagtail /app

# switch to the non-root user
exec gosu wagtail "$@"
```

I expect the CMD's `startup-main.sh` script to be executed next but I get this in the Docker Desktop logs when the container is started.

> ```
> Exited(1)
> Usage: gosu user-spec command [args]
>    gosu nobody:root bash -c 'whoami && id'
>    gosu 1000:1 idie: gosu tianon bash
>
> gosu version: 1.10 (go1.11.5 on linux/amd64; gc)
>    license: GPL-3 (full text at https://github.com/tianon/gosu)
> ```

I believe that Docker Desktop uses **root** when connecting to the container.

Maybe I'm missing something critical and/or this is something obvious. Please point me.

Comment: Does not look like you passed any args into startup-ssh.sh ... $@ would expand to those args, and seems to be empty.  hence the gosu error.

Comment: @Beel how does it differ from this one essentially? https://github.com/AppliedIS/dockerfiles/blob/master/alpine-gosu/3.7/gosu-entrypoint.sh. 
gosu expects a command: `gosu user-spec command [args]` and args are optional. But I don't actually (explicitly) see it in the attached example.
How do I proceed to the CMD script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code passed no arguments to the script. Imagine it like this:

```
bash -c '/app/startup-ssh.sh <NO ARGUMENTS HERE>' ignored ignored2 ignored3...
```

Test:

```
bash -c 'echo' 1
bash -c 'echo' 1 2
bash -c 'echo $0' 1 2 3
bash -c 'echo $1' 1 2 3
bash -c 'echo "$@"' 1 2 3
```

You want:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/app/startup-ssh.sh \"$@\"", "--"]
```

Or, why the explicit shell if the file has a shebang and is executable, really just:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/startup-ssh.sh"]
```

Comment: Does the latter expression - `ENTRYPOINT ["/app/startup-ssh.sh"]` - assume args are passed in automatically?

Comment: Yes. Like you would run the script from terminal...

Comment: Does gosu run `bash` without (implicitly) passing in the command?

Comment: I would strongly suspect it doesn't.